# How to slugify on get_root() function of django-mptt on overriding save method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `models.py`

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank = False, null = True, related_name = 'children')

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.parent:
            self.slug = slugify("%s %s" % (self.get_root(), self.name))
        else:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm trying to slugify the `root` and `name` fields here. Since the instance is not saved, i get this error `ValueError: Cannot call get_root on unsaved Category instances`.
I think i can save the instance first and then do the slugifying logic but that would result in hitting db multiple times. Is there any way i can slugify this effectively ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could call get_root on the parent item self.parent.

Comment: `self.slug = slugify("%s %s" % (self.parent.get_root(), self.name))`
Modified based on your answer.